# Problems with creating a DirectX 10 device and swap chain

Tags: c++, directx, directx-10, direct3d10

I am having some problems with creating a valid DirectX 10 device and swap chain using D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain. I think it might be my window creation that something goes wrong in since it says that the OutputWindow in the supplied SwapChainDesc is unused=??? (or a random int value)

This problem has been stressing me out since I can't seem to find out what is wrong with the project code

I know that it fails at line 193 in CDirect3D.cpp at

```
result = D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, 0, D3D10_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &this->m_swapChain, &this->m_device);
```

I would be very grateful if someone could take a look at the code. I've uploaded the project and its sources at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3605545/files/LearningEngine.zip

(Not a huge codebase, only 4 classes so far)

The project is in VS2010 and I used the DirectX SDK from June 2010

Comment: What code is returned? The error in `result` should point you in the right direction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205278(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I was trying the code from http://www.rastertek.com/dx10tut03.html and the code provided on the side have a NULL passed as adapter, yet it works

Comment: I found the problem, I mistyped this line
`swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;`
Should have been
`swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;`
Was hard to spot. Anyways, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, I mistyped this line:

```
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
```

Should have been:

```
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
```

Comment: +1: For good eyes because I looked at that about 4 times before I saw the difference.